# What $\oint\vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l}=51.5\mu T\cdot m$ mean?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, si-units

I've been stuck on this practice exam question. I'm supposed to find current through a loop using Ampere's law. But instead of $\mu_0$ it says $\mu$ and it's made me very confused because I can't get the right answer. Any help please?

Comment: Could it be a typo and they actually mean $\mu_0$, since they shouldn't be mixing up a prefix for units $\mu$ within the equation itself? It might be worth posting the entire question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That $\mu$ is the [prefix for micro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix), meaning $10^{-6}$.

The left hand side of that equation is telling you to integrate $\vec{B}\cdot \vec{\operatorname{d}\ell}$ around a closed loop. Usually, you'll have a loop where $|\vec{B}|$ is constant and its direction is along the loop, so you can just multiply $B$ times the perimeter of the loop. Usually.

Can't say more without more details on the problem.

Comment: @mrassassin777 - that being the case, you might want to "accept" this as the right answer (with the little check mark below the score).